# Which websites support U2F?

Tags: authentication, fido-u2f

FIDO Alliance's Universal 2nd Factor (U2F) is a new and promising approach to replace passwords. The FIDO Alliance comprises of many players but so far only Google website seems to support it. Are there other websites I can use to login with my U2F token?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security

Comment: U2F doesn't actually replace passwords; it augments them.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

See [www.dongleauth.info](https://www.dongleauth.com)
It contains a list of websites,
self-hosted software and USB dongles compatible to U2F (as well as One
Time Passwords).

Comment: It is working now. Either it got fixed or there might have been a problem on your end

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't have a U2F-*only* section / filter — you have to scroll through pages and pages of ancient, poorly-implemented OATH/OTP-implementing sites to find a single U2F entry. (Just a note.)

Answer (score -2):

So far only Google is supporting FIDO U2F authentication. There are plugins for self-hosted wordpress installes. No support for FIDO U2F on wordpress.com.

Comment: And Aero, and Box, and GitLab, and Sentry, and Fastmail, and SpaceCP, and more.